# Skip updating the content of the product according to the post meta field in WP all import plugin?

Tags: wordpress, wpallimport

I am using the WP all import plugin to import and update product from SMPT. I have used it's WooCommerce extension.
I have also created the meta field `_skip_on_update_key` which trigger '1' when you save that product from backend.

My issue is if `_skip_on_update_key` is `1` that that product should not be updated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use 'wp_all_import_is_post_to_update' filter hook to check which post to update or not. Following code should work for you:

```
function skip_to_update( $continue, $post_id, $xml_node, $import_id ) {
    if (get_post_meta($post_id, '_skip_on_update_key', true) == 1) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}

add_filter( 'wp_all_import_is_post_to_update', 'skip_to_update', 10, 4 );
```